# Approach class constant through class member variable

Tags: php, oop

I have trouble accessing a constant of a class via the object operator(`->`).

I have these 2 classes:

```
class withConstant {
    const MY_CONSTANT = 5;
}
class usingConstant {
    public $class = null;
    function __construct() {
        $this->class = new withConstant();
    }
}
```

When I do this:

```
$myClass = new usingConstant();
echo $myClass->class::MY_CONSTANT;
```

I get an error `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '::' (T_PAAMAYIM_NEKUDOTAYIM)`. However, I can get around it with this:

```
$myClass = new usingConstant();
$myClass = &$myClass->class;
echo $myClass::MY_CONSTANT;
```

I prefer to access the constant without assigning the member variable to another variable first.

Comment: Maybe the `usingConstant` class should [`extend`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/keyword.extends.php) `withConstant`?

Comment: Why do you have an `&` in your 2nd example?

Comment: Sam, that is not desirable. Lets say I could have more than 1 class that I want to access the constant of...
@rocket-hazmat That's a reference, so the variable doesn't get copied.
I'm unsure of why my question gets downvoted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the closest I can come to what you're actually after achieving unfortunately:

```
echo constant(get_class($myClass->class).'::MY_CONSTANT');
```

Note that this is incredibly inefficient, since it looks up the class to determine it's name, then looks it up again to reference the constant.

Comment: Thanks. This is the only desired answer I wanted so far. Unfortunately this is quite inefficient indeed. I just hoped there would be something like `{$myClass->class}::MY_CONSTANT` or similar.

Comment: @BennoZeeman: Unfortunately, in PHP, not everything can be written on one line ;-)

Comment: @BennoZeeman The issue here is the fact that you're not really supposed to reference class constants from a variable, the fact that you can has been tacked onto the language, and unfortunately isn't exactly free of bugs. If you desperately want to do it use RocketHaxmat's solution, otherwise rethink why you want to do this and if another solution is more appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

You can make a getter function in `withConstant` and call that.

```
class withConstant {
    const MY_CONSTANT = 5;

    function getConstant(){
        return self::MY_CONSTANT;
    }
}
```

Then you can call that function:

```
$myClass = new usingConstant();
echo $myClass->class->getConstant();
```

Comment: This is a good workaround, in my implementation however, the withConstant is actually a derived class. I don't want to define a new method in the class for every derived class. Thanks anyway!